# pickadate.js validation without making editable true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I have been looking for a workaround for making pickadate.js able to be validated on form submit but cant seem to get it to work with the required tag unless I make the editable attribute true. This causes the calendar not to pop up at all on my web page.

I was wondering if anyone has figured a way around this or will I have to set up my own form validation script in order to get this to work.